# How to upload image to node after cropping from ngx-image cropper in Angular on change event of file

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular8

Below is my function

```
UploadImage(){
  let file: File = this.fileToReturn; //fileToReturn is returned file from the cropper
  let formData:FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formData))

  formData.forEach((value,key) => {
     console.log(key+" "+value)
   })
  this.authservice.uploadPhoto(formData)
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      console.log('response received is ', response); 
    }
  )
  // debugger;
  // console.log(formData);
}
```

Upon logging the value to the console & server I get the empty json  **'{}'**.
What should be done?
Do I have to use any other libraries?

Comment: The resonse depends on what you send from the backend/route back to your service upon success/error. What exactly do you try to achieve? Have you had a look at multer already? -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: router.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
    var userdata = req.body
    console.log(req.body);        
})    I tried logging this and got empty json over there. I read about multer and am installing it

Comment: Yes , would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, waiting for the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UploadImage(){
  let file: File = this.fileToReturn;
  let formData:FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formData))

  formData.forEach((value,key) => {
     console.log(key+" "+value)
   })
  this.authservice.uploadPhoto(formData)
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      console.log('response received is ', response); 
      this.openSnackBar('Profile picture updated!','Close');
      // this.shared_user.getProfilepic(response);
    }
  )
  // debugger;
  // console.log(formData);
}
base64ToFile(data, filename) {

  const arr = data.split(',');
  const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
  const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
  let n = bstr.length;
  let u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

  while(n--){
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }

  return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
}

imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
      this.croppedImage = event.base64;
      console.log(this.croppedImage);
      this.fileToReturn = this.base64ToFile(
        event.base64,
        this.imageChangedEvent.target.files[0].name,
      )
      return this.fileToReturn
  }
```

This worked for me